# How to replace the ${BUILD_NUMBER} variable in efs files/code with jenkins dynamic build_number

Tags: linux, jenkins, amazon-s3, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

**Background**: I have a repository say example.com along with master and develop branch. My master branch repo push the change to "/efs/prod" through jenkins and develop branch repo push the change to "/efs/qa" through jenkins build.

**Requirement**: Now with jenkins build I am pushing a file say index.php with below cloudfront distribution url.

```
https://d2zjoj7go612la.cloudfront.net/img/secure.png?v=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

So I just want to run the jenkins build in such a way that the build should update the ${BUILD_NUMBER} variable with actual jenkins build number in index.php file that gets pushed to efs. In simple words how do we dynamically update the build number in the code pushed to efs.

[image]

I used above build-name-setter plugin to get the build_number but how could I dynamically update it in the index.php file and in all the efs files where we have ${BUILD_NUMBER} defined

Comment: I have also tried to use EnvInject plugin but still not able to dynamically update the index.php with actual build number.

Answer (score 0):

I used below sed command to replace the build number variable dynamically in the code

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/##BUILD_NUMBER##/${BUILD_NUMBER}/g" {} +
```